# htaccess non-www redirect specific directory to www directory

Tags: .htaccess, web

I've got a strange issues with my htaccess file, and I am a newbie at best with htaccess...

I have cloud-flare (CF) on my hosting account, which also makes a wrinkle to this.  Also I have multiple sub-domains running on the site as well.  It is multi-site wordpress.

My SEO advisors are asking to ensure that my-dir is properly redirected to www.

The first rule was added by way of the redirect options at my host.

Because CF must have traffic on subdomain (either www, or something else) they put in an htaccess rule, as illustrated below:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
    RewriteRule ^my\-dir\/$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/my\-dir\/" [R=301,L]

   # Start CloudFlare:mydomain.com rewrite. Do not Edit 
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 
   # End CloudFlare rewrite.
```

Now what I see is - if you navigate to mydomain.com/my-dir/ I get routed to www.mydomain.com.  I'm not sure why this is...

As I've been testing I've emptied the cache etc...

Thanks!  Scott

Comment: Just a comment, having www. in your domain name will not make any difference for the search engines. Plus it can give you issues with cookies. Always avoid the www, the www is not needed anymore.

Comment: Alec - thanks for that, it is a requirement for cloud-flare to route the traffic properly - unless they've changed it recently.  Otherwise I would ditch it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have wordpress installations in directories like `/my-dir/`, then you need to add rules to the htaccess files found in those directories. Any rewrite rules in htaccess files in sub directories completely supersede any rules found in all parent directories. So you'd need to add something similar in the htaccess file in your `my-dir` directory, **above any wordpress rules**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/my-dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I moved the redirect code in the first part of the htaccess file above the word-press rules <code>RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^my\-dir\/$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/my-dir/$1 [R=301,L]</code>